# JQuery .insertAfter() DOM elements

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have a HTML Table which in which i want to manipulate using JQuery

Table:

```
<tr><td>----Parent One
<Table id="ChildID" >----Child One

First TR1<TR>

<TD><div class=ExternalClass00FA6D5A488C4B2582667D6D8DF15F79>Value 1</div></TD>

<TD class="ms-disc-bordered-noleft">Value 2</TD>

<TD class="ms-disc-bordered-noleft">Value 3</TD>

<TD class="ms-disc-bordered-noleft">
<A HREF="/Threaded.aspx?RootFolder=%2fLists&amp;FolderCTID=0x01200">Value 4</A>
</TD></TR>

..........

Second TR2<TR>

<TD><div class=ExternalClass00FA6D5A488C4B2582667D6D8DF15F79>Value 1</div></TD>

<TD class="ms-disc-bordered-noleft">Value 2</TD>

<TD class="ms-disc-bordered-noleft">Value 3</TD>

<TD class="ms-disc-bordered-noleft">
<A HREF="/Threaded.aspx?RootFolder=%2fLists&amp;FolderCTID=0x01200">Value 4</A>
</TD></TR>

........and so on

</TABLE>---Child One

</td></tr></TABLE>---Parent One
```

i am trying to pick "Value 4" the last  having string "FolderCTID" in href and insertBefore "Value 1" with div class that starts with "ExternalClass".

I want to insertBefore the each element in the row to the corresponding element in the same row

I am using following code:

$('a[href*="FolderCTID"]').insertBefore($('div[class^="ExternalClass"]'));

But it is inserting all the elements for every row....i think i should make something to specify the entities and loop around** each end of the entity...

Please help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then you may want this,
try this , and let me know,

```
$('a[href*="FolderCTID"]').each(
    function(){
        $(this).parents('tr').find('div[class^="ExternalClass"]').before(this);
    }
);
```

Comment: again it is same...collectively taking all the elements in a column and inserting that collection(all elements) in every row

Comment: your's script absolutely correct im sorry to **update the script above again**...in my case when i write **$(this).parents('tr').find('div[class^="ExternalClass"]').before(this);** it is considering some Parent One <tr> and giving wrong output ..**i need to work around the <TABLE id="ChildID">----Child One and ended with </TABLE>---Child One**  How to do this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a[href*="FolderCTID"]').each(
    function(){
        $(this).siblings(':first').insertBefore(this);
    }
)
```

may this help.

Comment: Do u mean as :  '$('a[href*="FolderCTID"]').each( function(){ $(this).siblings($('div[class^="ExternalClass"]')).insertBefore(this); } ) ;'   But unfortunately it is returning the same as i did before....it is inserting bunch of all the elements to every element that we are inserting before....I am looking for **each element in the same row**